# How to compare regression coefficients for logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, regression-coefficients

I have two logistic regression models that are exactly the same (same IVs and same sample) but a different DV. Is there a simple way to compare the regression coefficients between these two models? No nesting involved, though there is multiple imputation (if that matters)

We are trying to see if an IV is a better predictor for DV A vs. DV B. Trying to see where there is a stronger relation

Comment: Please edit the question to say more about the type of comparison you have in mind and what you hope to learn from the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I would exactly call this simple, but here is one way that works. Create one dataset that only contains one of the outcomes and all of the predictors, and create another dataset that only contains the other outcome and all of the predictors. Append the datasets longwise, adding a new variable representing which dataset each row comes from. You should have a new dataset with twice as many rows as you started with, a single dependent variable, and a new variable containing the dataset membership.

From here, you fit a single logistic regression model for the outcome, but you include an interaction between dataset membership and every predictor. The coefficient on each product term represents the difference between the coefficients in the two original models (i.e., the difference between the coefficient in the model predicting one outcome and the coefficient in model predicting the other outcome).

Below is how you would do this in R, with outcomes `Y1` and `Y2` and predictors `A` and `B`:

```r
set.seed(1)
n <- 1e4
A <- rnorm(n)
B <- rbinom(n, 1, .3)

Y1 <- rbinom(n, 1, plogis(1 + A + B))
Y2 <- rbinom(n, 1, plogis(-1 + 2*A + 3*B))

D0 <- data.frame(Y1, Y2, A, B)
```

First let's fit the models separately:

```r
fit1 <- glm(Y1 ~ A + B, data = D0, family = binomial)
fit2 <- glm(Y2 ~ A + B, data = D0, family = binomial)

summary(fit1)$coef
#>              Estimate Std. Error  z value      Pr(>|z|)
#> (Intercept) 0.9831919 0.02932530 33.52709 1.942439e-246
#> A           0.9772295 0.02877720 33.95846 9.148440e-253
#> B           0.9918479 0.06108163 16.23807  2.713229e-59
summary(fit2)$coef
#>               Estimate Std. Error   z value      Pr(>|z|)
#> (Intercept) -0.9992999 0.03395217 -29.43258 2.104052e-190
#> A            1.9364369 0.04170307  46.43392  0.000000e+00
#> B            2.9519656 0.07305699  40.40634  0.000000e+00
```

Now let's do the hack I described earlier:

```r
D1 <- cbind(D0[c("Y1", "A", "B")], outcome = "1")
names(D1)[1] <- "Y"

D2 <- cbind(D0[c("Y2", "A", "B")], outcome = "2")
names(D2)[1] <- "Y"

D <- rbind(D1, D2)
```

Finally, we can fit the combine model.

```r
fit <- glm(Y ~ outcome * (A + B), data = D, family = binomial)

summary(fit)$coef
#>               Estimate Std. Error   z value      Pr(>|z|)
#> (Intercept)  0.9831919 0.02932530  33.52709 1.942439e-246
#> outcome2    -1.9824918 0.04486338 -44.18953  0.000000e+00
#> A            0.9772295 0.02877720  33.95846 9.148440e-253
#> B            0.9918479 0.06108163  16.23807  2.713229e-59
#> outcome2:A   0.9592075 0.05066827  18.93113  6.319463e-80
#> outcome2:B   1.9601176 0.09522757  20.58351  3.857119e-94
```

Notice the coefficients and standard errors for the terms that don't involve the `outcome2` variable are identical to those in the original model for `Y1` (i.e., because `1` is the reference level for `outcome`). The sum of each coefficient and its interaction with `outcome2` is equal to the corresponding coefficient in the model for `Y2`. The interaction terms represent the differences between the coefficients. The `outcome2` coefficient represents the difference between the intercepts of the two models.

As @clementzach mentioned, it might be useful to add a correction for multiple comparisons using `p.adjust()`.

For an omnibus test of whether the two models have any different coefficients, you can perform a likelihood ratio test between `fit` and a version of fit with the `outcome` variable excluded (or included if you don't want to include the possible difference in the intercept). An example below:

```r
fit_ <- glm(Y ~ A + B, data = D, family = binomial)

anova(fit_, fit, test = "LRT")
#> Analysis of Deviance Table
#> 
#> Model 1: Y ~ A + B
#> Model 2: Y ~ outcome * (A + B)
#>   Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance  Pr(>Chi)    
#> 1     19997      20864                          
#> 2     19994      18154  3     2710 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

The significant 3df test indicates at least one of the coefficients differs between the two models.

For multiply imputed data, you will need to extract the imputed datasets and perform this operation one by one, then combine the results of the combined model using the standard pooling rules for multiply imputed data (e.g., using `mitools::MIcombine()`). Performing an LRT on multiply imputed data is not straightforward, so you may not be able to do the omnibus test.

Comment: thank you for your very detailed reply!

Comment: No problem. If it solved your problem please select the answer so it is not lingering.

Comment: I am new here...I think I just changed it to answered?

Comment: Nope, there might be a checkmark next to the score that you need to click.

Answer (score 0):

You could pool the standard errors of the coefficients generated for the same covariate by different models and do a wald test on the difference between the two coefficients using that standard error.

But, you would have alpha inflation due to multiple testing, and you wouldn’t be comparing the whole models to each other.

What would be your purpose in comparing the coefficients in the models? What would your null and alternative hypotheses be?

Comment: thank you! we are trying to see if one IV is a stronger predictor in model A vs. model B (null coefficients equal, alternative unequal)